# Programmatically writing to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I have an ASP.Net website which is connected to an SQL Server. In a previous project (VB) I used the following code to write to my database:

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnection").ConnectionString
                Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO tblProfile(UserID, UserName, Title, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, DateofBirth, Gender, HomePhoneNumber, MobilePhoneNumber, Address, StreetName, StreetType, Suburb, PostCode, State, Country) VALUES(@UserID, @UserName, @Title, @FirstName, @LastName, @MiddleName, @DateofBirth, @Gender, @HomePhoneNumber, @MobilePhoneNumber, @Address, @StreetName, @StreetType, @Suburb, @PostCode, @State, @Country)"

                Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    myConnection.Open()
                    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", newUserGuid)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", newUserName)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title.SelectedItem.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName.Text)
                    If MiddleNames.Text = String.Empty Then
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", DBNull.Value)
                    Else
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MiddleNames.Text)
                    End If
                    DateofBirth.Text = YearofBirth.Text + "-" + MonthofBirth.Text + "-" + DayofBirth.Text
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofBirth", DateofBirth.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedItem.Text)
                    If HomePhoneNumber.Text = String.Empty Then
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", DBNull.Value)
                    Else
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePhoneNumber", HomePhoneNumber.Text)
                    End If
                    If MobilePhoneNumber.Text = String.Empty Then
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhoneNumber", DBNull.Value)
                    Else
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobilePhoneNumber", MobilePhoneNumber.Text)
                    End If
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", AddressNumber.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetName", StreetName.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StreetType", StreetType.SelectedItem.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suburb", Suburb.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", Postcode.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State.SelectedItem.Text)
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country.SelectedItem.Text)

                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    myConnection.Close()
                End Using
```

I've now changed to C#, and am having problems altering this code. So far I have:

```
String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;

String insertSql = "INSERT INTO tbl_UserProfiles VALUES(@UserID, @FirstName, @LastName, @YearOfBirth, @Country)";
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, connectionString);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", newUserGuid);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstNameTB.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastNameTB.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfBirth", YearDDL.SelectedItem.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", CountryDDL.SelectedItem.Text);

try
{
    connectionString.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

finally
{
    connectionString.Close();
}
```

Which I've tried to create after looking at a few tutorial sites and my own previous code. But, I believe I'm doing something wrong here:

```
String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
```

as I get the squiggly red underline.

Comment: What the "red underline" say?

Comment: Sorry about that: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)` you did not convert this line to C#

Comment: You can still use the Using statements around the connection and command objects.

Comment: The first code is my old code, from an old project. The second code is my new code for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `Open()` a connection string :)

Translate

```
  Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    myConnection.Open()
      Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection)
```

To

```
  using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection))
  {
      myConnection.Open();
      ...
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

using in C# on your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` will guarantee that `Dispose()` is called on both objects, irrespective of whether success or fail (and close connections, cleanup etc)

Answer (score 2):

try this....
Use `SqlConnection`

**Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString) you did not convert this line to C#**

```
 String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
 SqlConnection con = new Sqlconnection(connectionString);
            String insertSql = "INSERT INTO tbl_UserProfiles VALUES(@UserID, @FirstName, @LastName, @YearOfBirth, @Country)";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, con);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", newUserGuid);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstNameTB.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastNameTB.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfBirth", YearDDL.SelectedItem.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", CountryDDL.SelectedItem.Text);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
using System.Configuration
```

at the top of the file. Also does your web.config file contain a configuration > configSections > configSections section?

Comment: Why would it matter if a configSections section is present or not?